# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Sframe'

Tags: python, graphlab, sframe

I installed Dato's `GraphLab Create` to run with `python 27` first directly from its executable then manually via `pip` ([instructions here](https://dato.com/products/create/)) for troubleshooting.

Code:

```
import graphlab
graphlab.SFrame()
```

Output:

```
[INFO] Start server at: ipc:///tmp/graphlab_server-4908 
- Server binary: C:\Users\Remi\Anaconda2\envs\dato-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\unity_server.exe 
- Server log: C:\Users\Remi\AppData\Local\Temp\graphlab_server_1455637156.log.0
[INFO] GraphLab Server Version: 1.8.1
```

Now, attempt to load a .csv file as an Sframe:

```
csvsf = graphlab.Sframe('file.csv')
```

complains:

```
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-68278493c023> in <module>()
 ----> 1 sf = graphlab.Sframe('file.csv')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Sframe'
```

Any idea(s) how to pinpoint the issue? Thanks so much.

Note: Uninstalled an already present `python 34` version

Comment: There is a typo - `SFrame` should have a capitalized "F".

Comment: @ papayawarrior: wow thanks. I thought the issue was much deeper.

Answer (score 1):

capitalization error, it should be SFrame, not Sframe

Comment: this answer does not add any new information, as the exact info was given as a comment on Feb 16

Answer (score 0):

You can only load a graplab package ('file.gl') by `graphlab.SFrame()`.
Instead to load a csv file use `csvf = graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('file.csv')`
for more information and other data types read this docs
https://dato.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.data_structures.html